# What does it mean to square a partial derivative with a one dimensional vector (scalar)?

Tags: partial-derivative, quantum-mechanics

Please bear with me..

[image: Schrodinger Equation]

In the above image, we need to substitute **p<sup>2</sup>** from the partial derivative (pay attention to content in red boxes).
If we're considering the one dimensional case, we can either take a second derivative or square the equation to obtain **p<sup>2</sup>**.
However, the result won't be the same when substituted (Obviously, as expression has changed).
Since **p** is a vector here (momentum), we can't square anyway. But if we're only considering **x** (one-dimension) then it should be okay, right?

I don't understand how we can get to expressions for **p<sup>2</sup>** with these two methods (squaring and second derivative) :(

Am I missing something? What does it mean to square a partial derivative?
Please help.

Comment: You can "square" a vector: $\mathbf p\cdot \mathbf p$

Comment: Well how would you know whether to use dot product or cross product? In this context, for example..

Comment: Cross product of a vector with itself is always zero. More generally, one can consider the result returned by the formula: is it scalar or vector?

Comment: Here result has to be vector (momentum). But squaring will yield 0 (cross product with itself). But that would be wrong. I dont think we can square a vector like this. Please share an example..

Comment: Read up on the [Laplacian](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Laplace_operator): it appears to underlie your misconception.

Comment: @CosmasZachos Yes, you're right. That part is now clear to me, thanks. But now I'm confused how we arrive at $\vec{p}=-i\hbar \nabla$ from $\hat{p}=-i\hbar \frac{\partial}{\partial x}$ and $E=i\hbar \frac{\partial}{\partial t}$? I understand $\nabla=\frac{\partial}{\partial x}\hat{e_x}+\frac{\partial}{\partial t}\hat{e_y}$.